# Check if all VISIBLE select boxes have something selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have hidden select boxes and every time I try to check if all the select boxes are selected and it keeps including the hidden ones, how can i make the following code only work for visible select boxes? have tried `.filter(':visible')` but didn't help?

```
if($('option[disabled]:selected').length == 0){
   // ALL the select boxes have something selected rather than the default option
   alert("success");
}else{
    alert("fail");
}
```

**The one of the visible select boxes:**

```
<div class="one-wrap">
  <label for="one-amount">one</label>
  <div id="one-select-wrap">    
    <select id="one-amount" class="" name="">
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an amount -- </option>
      <option value="1000">100 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">225 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">450 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">1 750 000 one</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And a hidden example:**

```
<div class="two-wrap hidden">
  <label for="two-amount">two</label>
  <div id="two-select-wrap">    
    <select id="two-amount" class="" name="">
      <option disabled selected value> -- select an amount -- </option>
      <option value="1000">200 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">430 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">260 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">500 000 two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try iterating over all checked boxes, then use `closest` and `length` to see if a parent element has hidden class.

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var message = "success";  
    $('select').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == null && $(this).closest('.hidden').length == 0 ) {
            message = "fail";  
        }
    }); 
    alert(message);
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/daveybrown/pen/BprxZa)

Comment: Thanks for your time but this doesn't seem to work even when the two errors are fixed in your code (the extra curly bracket in the function and the message var in quotes).

Comment: Thanks this is perfect :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of iterating, you can just query for `select`s that are in a div that is not hidden. For your example, try

```
$('div:not(.hidden) div select')
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your parent div a class, like `divs`

```
<div class="one-wrap divs">
<div class="one-wrap divs hidden">  //ASSUMING THIS HAS display:none
```

Now traverse

```
$(".divs:visible").each(function(){
    var select = $(this).find("select");
    //YOUR CODE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the visible divs:

```
function checkAllSelected() {
    var unselected = 0;
    $('.two-wrap').not('.hidden').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('option:selected').not('[disabled]').length === 0) {
           unselected++;
        }
    });
    return unselected === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can match the count of select with no option selected with the count of hidden select

```js
$("#one-amount,#two-amount").on("change", function() {
  if ($('select option[disabled]:selected').length == $(".hidden select").length) {
    alert("success");
  } else {
    alert("fail");
  }

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-wrap">
  <label for="one-amount">one</label>
  <div id="one-select-wrap">
    <select id="one-amount" class="" name="">
      <option disabled selected value>-- select an amount --</option>
      <option value="1000">100 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">225 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">450 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">1 750 000 one</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="two-wrap">
  <label for="one-amount">two</label>
  <div id="two-select-wrap">
    <select id="two-amount" class="" name="">
      <option disabled selected value>-- select an amount --</option>
      <option value="1000">100 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">225 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">450 000 one</option>
      <option value="1000">1 750 000 one</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="two-wrap hidden">
  <label for="two-amount">two</label>
  <div id="two-select-wrap">
    <select id="two-amount" class="" name="">
      <option disabled selected value>-- select an amount --</option>
      <option value="1000">200 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">430 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">260 000 two</option>
      <option value="1000">500 000 two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```